# Frequency domain analysis of steering system of a car

Tags: dynamics, vibration, electric-vehicles, car, frequency-response

Can anyone share the equations involved, or some relevant theory material for frquency domain analysis of steering rack and pinion using bode plot?

Comment: Are thy on a Nascar track or Brands Hatch?

Comment: It doesn't matter which, I am asking in general